# Calculating the residue with series that has negative powers

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I want to calculate the residue of $f(z)=(z-sin(z))^{-1}=\frac{1}{z^3}+ \frac{3}{10z}+..$ at 0. We get that expansion using binomial theorem using provided $z$ small the residue of $f$ at $a$ is $\displaystyle \lim_{z \to a} (z-a)f(z)$ . I need $a=0$. So multiply by $z$ to get: $\frac{1}{z^2}+ \frac{3}{10}+...$. Apparently the residue is $\frac{3}{10}$. How is this possible- wouldn't $\frac{1}{z^2}$ tend to $\infty$ as $z$ tends to $0$?

Comment: The residue is **always** the coefficient of $\;(z-z_0)^{-1}\;$ , with $\;z_0\;$ the singularity that's been treated.

Comment: But why...- If you pretend you don't know that why does it not fit with what I've done?

Comment: @Ar I don't understand your point: the residue is that because **that is its definition**, as simple as that. Why is it important is very easy to explain and even to prove its importance in the complex integration of a very wide range of functions.